# S3 inventory query in Athena

Tags: amazon-athena

I have s3 inventory service setup done for an s3 bucket. I have imported data into Athena in CSV format. Is there a way that I can query number of objects in a particular s3 directory in Athena ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try this to get the number of objects

```
SELECT COUNT("$path") from TABLE_NAME
```